What to use for self monitoring a wired security system
I have an Ademco 4120XM that was installed into a brand new house built in the late 90s. I don’t want to pay a monitoring company to monitor it, so what would be some options to self monitor it? Here are some pictures of the panel



monitor how, like a app on cellphone,

Yeah something like that where I could also remotely arm and disarm

how much of this do you want to self-host or are you fine using a different cloud service like amazon or google?

I am fine with anything as long as it’s free and I am able to arm/disarm it from anywhere

Are you currently able to remotely arm and disarm ?  I mean is that a service your provider can give with your existing hardware.

No the only way to arm/disarm is through the keypad and I am trying to avoid the security companies because it’s 60$ a month to get it monitored and I just want to self monitor it

You have probably arrived at a point where things your nearly 30 year old system was never deigned to do are best "added" by replacing it with one that offers what you want. Hopefully you can re-use the wiring in place. You might be able to reuse the sensors; you might not, depending on the new system and the old system. You might like to have your 1997 Subaru self-drive, but it's not going to be practical to get there. Same logic applies to this antique and remote arm/disarm/etc.

For someone knowledgeable in electronics, computers and the internet, it certainly would be possible, and not too difficult to monitor and control the system remotely, e.g., via cell phone. However, this would take some improvising, so you'd need to hire someone competent and trustworthy to do it for you. BTW, monitoring rates in my are are about 1/3 that, ~US$60 for thee months. You might find another monitoring service, and discuss having them take over: https://www.usnews.com/360-reviews/services/home-security, https://www.google.com/search?q=alarm+monitoring+services

IMHO a better and simpler route would be to simply delete that and install something like SimpliSafe.

Hard to say for sure, but based on age I suspect that this system is designed only to call out on an ordinary phone line and send a low bit-rate message to a monitoring system. There does not appear to be any Ethernet connection or even a standard (by which I mean RS-232 or similar, not USB) serial port.
You might be able to use a microcontroller with a bunch of I/O pins to monitor the alarm output and to control some functions. But I suspect the only way to properly control it would be to emulate the console (keypad/display), and by the time you figure out how to do that, you might as well just buy a new system or build one yourself using a microcontroller.

The system is modular, there is a serial bus that communicates with the keypads, POTS communicator, cellular communicators, and a customized Netgear router.  OP may not have any of these modules, and I agree the time spent learning it would be better spent building or buying a new system.

TIL the community blogs for Home Assistant and Smart Things both have some apparently bored people building Ademco interfaces and open source.  And many more Netgear routers have serial interfaces unused and undocumented on the mother board.  Still I agree with the conclusion here so not making this an answer.

You could buy, stand alone auto-diallers for pots.  There are probably some around for VOIP (Voice over IP).  You record a message on them.  They dial out  and play the message when an input activates.
The problem is that you will be paying for a SIM card and a mobile connection, which may not be much different to monitoring it.
I am assuming that the system is small (otherwise you should be going to a professional).  You can buy DIY alarm kits at a reasonable price.

Home assistant seems to support Ademco, if you want something that lasts that's probably the best way to go. this will be some sort of device that connects to your alarm as a console and provides web access.
The alternative of replacing the alarm system with a cloud enabled system puts you at mercy of the vendor, and cloud vendors seem to last about 5 years on average.  Or going with a paid provider, they will be motivated to maintain support.

The clear favorite (so far, anyway) in alarm panel replacements for smarthome purposes is Konnected. It is a microcontroller-based system that replaces the circuit panels and uses the existing wired sensors, and connects to your favorite smarthome ecosystem. (I am not affiliated with Konnected, I did research on replacing my own security system with something "smarter").
I hesitate to recommend anything here especially in the smarthome space - DIY.SE in general does not do product recommendations because things change rapidly - doubly so for smarthome/IOT. But Konnected has been around a long time, is still pretty popular, and no one has mentioned it in an answer here yet. I think it might work for you (after a lot of install & configuration work).
